# Still getting wrong answer after trying to solve $x''(t)+4x(t)=t^2$ where $x(0)=1$ and $x'(0)=2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

I am trying to solve this differential equation:

$$x''(t)+4x(t)=t^2,x(0)=1,x'(0)=2$$

The answer should be:

$$x(t)=\frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{9}{8}\cos{2t}+\sin{2t}$$

Which is also verified by WolframAlpha. But instead I got by calculating by hand:

$$x(t)=\frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{9}{8}\cos{2t}+\sin{2t}$$

Here's how I got it.  The Laplace transform of the differential equation is:

$$s^2X(s)-sx(0)-x'(0)+4X(s)=\frac{2}{s^3}$$

Since $x(0)=1$ and $x'(0)=2$:

$$s^2X(s)-s-2+4X(s)=\frac{2}{s^3}$$

Solving for $X(s)$:

$$X(s)=\frac{s^4+2s^3+2}{s^3(s^2+4)}=\frac{s^4+2s^3+2}{s^3(s+j2)(s-j2)}$$

Breaking it up into partial fractions:

$$X(s)=\frac{A}{s^3}+\frac{B}{s^2}+\frac{C}{s}+\frac{D}{s+j2}+\frac{E}{s-j2}$$

Solving for the coefficients:

$$
\begin{align}
A &= s^3X(s)|_{s=0} = \frac{1}{2} \\
D &= (s+j2)X(s)|_{s=-j2} = \frac{9}{16}+j\frac{1}{2} \\
E &= (s-j2)X(s)|_{s=j2} = \frac{9}{16}-j\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{align}
$$

But this part is where I think I calculated wrong but couldn't figure out why:

$$
\begin{align}
B &= [\frac{d}{ds}s^3X(s)]_{s=0} = \frac{d}{ds}(\frac{s^4+2s^3+2}{s^2+4})|_{s=0}\\
&=\frac{(4s^3+6s^2)(s^2+4)-(s^4+2s^3+2)(2s)}{(s^2+4)^2}|_{s=0} \\ &=\frac{2s^5+2s^4+16s^3+24s^2-4s}{s^4+8s^2+16}|_{s=0} = 0 
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
C &= [\frac{d^2}{ds^2}s^3X(s)]_{s=0}=\frac{d}{ds}\frac{2s^5+2s^4+16s^3+24s^2-4s}{s^4+8s^2+16}|_{s=0} \\
&= \frac{(10s^4+8s^3+48s^2+48s-4)(s^4+8s^2+16)-(2s^5+2s^4+16s^3+24s^2-4s)(4s^3+16s)}{(s^4+8s^2+16)^2}|_{s=0} \\
&= \frac{(-4)(16)}{(16)^2} = \frac{-1}{4}
\end{align}
$$
Substituting in the coefficients:
$$X(s)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{s^3}-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{s}+(\frac{9}{16}+j\frac{1}{2})\cdot\frac{1}{s+j2}+(\frac{9}{16}-j\frac{1}{2})\cdot\frac{1}{s-j2}$$
Then do inverse Laplace transform:
$$
\begin{align}
x(t) &= \frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{4}+(\frac{9}{16}+j\frac{1}{2})e^{-j2t}+(\frac{9}{16}-j\frac{1}{2})e^{j2t}\\
&= \frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{9}{8}(\frac{e^{j2t}+e^{-j2t}}{2})+(\frac{e^{j2t}-e^{-j2t}}{j2})\\
&=\frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{9}{8}\cos{2t}+\sin{2t}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'd say this one would be easier to do with undetermined coefficients. Find a particular solution in the form of a quadratic polynomial; the homogeneous solution is easy to see; then choose the coefficients for the homogeneous part appropriately to satisfy the initial conditions. (Or you could combine the approaches: find the particular solution, which is $\frac{2t^2-1}{8}$. Then consider $z=y-\frac{2t^2-1}{8}$, so that $z''+4z=0$, $z(0)=\frac{9}{8},z'(0)=2$, and use a Laplace transform on that.)

Comment: C should be $-\frac{1}{8}$, since comparing coefficients of $s^2$ gives $0=A+4C$

Comment: I could still do your methods, but it still bothers me why C = -1/4 using my method. Is the method itself wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your method, but it's not hard to see that it will give 2C rather than C.

Answer (score 3):

I found out why I am wrong according to http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/BackGround/PartialFraction/RootsRepeat.html

For any multiply repeated roots (n>2), the coefficient $A_k$ should be:

$$
A_k=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\Big[\frac{d^{(k-1)}}{ds^{(k-1)}}(s+a)^nF(s)\Big]_{s=-a}
$$

Therefore, $C$ should be:

$$
C=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\frac{d^2}{ds^2}s^3X(s)\Big]_{s=0}
$$